# Is my Verizon tablet affected by spectre/meltdown?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, tablet, malware, verizon

i have an old Verizon tablet (ellipses 7) and i was wondering if it's included in  the specter/meltdown CPU bugs that are going around and if there is anyway to update my software to protect it?

Comment: Unless Google backports the patch to earlier versions of Android, I doubt that versions before Android Oreo will get the patch at all. You might have to look into getting a custom ROM for the device, assuming that you can flash a bootloader and find a compatible ROM for it in the first place.

Comment: yeah thanks! that what i figured - which is why i asked [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/189393/how-to-force-upgrade-my-tablet) question